# Popup listview to appear on ItemClickListener of another listview

Tags: java, android, listview, popup

I have a `ListView` inside my app that I want to a popup `ListView` appears when I clicked on each Item of first `ListView` but the second `ListView` which have to be in popup view doesn't appears.
Here is my whole `OnCreate` code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView users =  findViewById(R.id.users);
    String[] values = new String[] { "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    users.setAdapter(adapter);
    users.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListView todo =new ListView(MainActivity.this);
            String[] itemss={"Kick","Make Admin","Mute"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,itemss);
            todo.setAdapter(adapter);
            todo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
                        position, long id) {
                    ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)view;
                    TextView txt=(TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,txt.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    final CharSequence[] items = {"Delete User","Add User","Ban User"};
                    final ArrayList selectedItems=new ArrayList();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Admin accesses");
                    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                selectedItems.add(which);
                            } else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As you see in the code I want to a popup checkbox appear by click on each second `ListView` Item but first I have to fix the issue of appearing the second `ListView`
Does anyone know how can I fix this?
Is this possibles to popup showing a `ListView` on `OnItemVlickListener` of another `ListView`?

Comment: Where do you expect that `ListView todo` to display? As you currently have it, it's basically discarded at the end of `users`' `onItemClick()` because you're not adding it to anything, like the `Activity`, or a `Dialog`.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. thanks a lot for your response . how can I add my second listview into my activity?

Comment: Ah, OK, I was just writing a comment to clarify my question. So, you want `todo` to be in the `Activity`, and then the delete/add/ban `AlertDialog` pops up from that? How do you want `todo` to display? Is it replacing/covering everything else in the `Activity`? Or is it going into a certain spot?

Comment: Actually, it would be better – and easier – to just put it in `activity_main` with its `visibility` set to `gone`. Then, when you need it, set it to `VISIBLE`, and hide any other `View`s that you might need to. Even better than that would be to use `Fragment`s here, but that might be a little ahead of things.

Comment: @MikeM. just forget about AlertDialog it doesn't matter now , I want to second Listview be appeared like popup when I'm clicking on each First ListView Item but I don't know where and how should I add my secondList view

Comment: @MikeM. I think I should use alert adapter instead of listview

Comment: If you want it to pop up, then you could have another `AlertDialog` for it. You can call `setView(todo)` on another `AlertDialog.Builder`, and `show()` that in `users`' `onItemClick()`. Follow me?

Comment: instead of poping another listview try using a spinner.It will be much easier and it will popup onItemclick just like you said

Comment: @MikeM. Yes , I think this is the write way , thanks a lot for your time answer this to I accept your answer

Comment: Oh, it's cool. I just gave a broad suggestion. Not really worthy of an answer. Thanks, though. Feel free to post an answer yourself, when you get it working, to show exactly how you solved it. Good luck with your project. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot man you just saved my day Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **not added second listview** onto the parent view (Activity / Your parent layout like Relative layout / Linear Layout etc).

> You need to **add your listview todo** to the **parent layout** and
>   **need to define layout params**.

For Example :-

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout_parent);
    ListView todo=new ListView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    todo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    relativeLayoutParent.addView(todo);
```

> In above example, I make assumption that your layout parent is
>   Relative layout.

And for Pop Up:-

Change below code to

```
 builder.create();
 builder.show();
```

this

```
AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

***It will display your multiple chicle alert dialog.***

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your response , how can I add my listview todo to the parent layout and define layout params ? sorry can you please write the code?

Comment: @ShakibKarami I have update my answer, by making some assumptions. Otherwise Can you please add your **activity_main.xml** code.